# Copy fields from one list to another using SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Can I copy a particular field items of one SharePoint list to another using SharePoint Designer? In my case both the lists have different fields but some fields in common. I want to copy the common columns alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with the help of workflow or using custom action with Client Object Model.

One example could be using the Content and Structure feature (https://SPDevURL/_Layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx) and selecting the items you wish to copy and pasting them in the new list.

Another option could be opening the list by exporting to Excel and copying the corresponding cells into the new list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do this using 'Workflows'.

When a new item in created or edited in 'List 1', you can setup a worfklow that creates or updates another item in 'List 2' using the various fields you want to match on.

You need be able to effectively 'match' the two items between the two lists, so as long as you can identify the item in list 2 you want to update or copy fields to, this shouldnt be a problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. You can use designer workflow. Please look [here](http://anagaraju.blogspot.in/2012/06/copy-item-from-one-list-to-another.html)

2 Use SharePoint 2010 object model. I am not sure wether you can get it by using any out of box features.

http://www.fewlines4biju.com/search/label/SharePoint%20Object%20Model